# How React native and Android Instant Apps will play along? Any thoughts?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-instant-apps

Google recently announced android instant app. Which basically is code splitting. Will this work with React native apps, since react native build will generate main js bundle.

Any thoughts how one can take best of both the technology, Especially with Hybrid React Native Android Apps?

Comment: React native doesn't currently work with Android Instant Apps.  It's due to the fact that that NDK support in Instant Apps isn't complete and need some work. The team is working on it.

Comment: NDK is supported on Android 5.0 and higher now! https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html#project-structure But do let them know if there are incompatibilities lurking somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

NDK is supported on Android 5.0 and higher now! But do let them know if there are incompatibilities lurking somewhere.

[**Reference**](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html#project-structure)

you can also check [facebook/react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14197)